# technique for side handles on cutting board

Tags: technique

Ive seen cutting boards with metal handles installed  from the side faces that don't appear to have any outside facing screw holes.. how the heck are they doing this?

Comment: Without photos, all we cannot do is guess. I could suggest hanger bolts, but I have no evidence.

Comment: If they just disappear into a slot cut in the wood they could be glued in place. Alternatively if you have never seen the underside they could be held by screws driven in from the bottom..

Comment: Welcome to the Woodworking.SE! It would be very helpful if you can add some photos of examples, as keshlam mentioned.

Comment: thanks guys, here is a link to something similar. I can't get a photo of the actual board I saw however this is the closest thing i've found. I inspected the bottom and nothing to suggest it had been screwed from the underside. Glue seemed like the only viable option if so what would be the best method if the handle was designed to be screwed from the back. Not sure about this example but at least you can see what I mean. http://www.houzz.com/photos/27764776/Farmhouse-Cutting-Board-with-Side-Handles-industrial-cutting-boards - thanks for the welcome guys.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible methods for mounting these handles.  The first is to use a cross dowel nut and threaded rods mounted from a hole on the underside of the cutting board.  [image: cross dowel]

The second is to use hanger bolts set into the cutting board in oversized drilled openings using epoxy.

[image: hanger bolt]

Comment: I agree, I think epoxy is probably the only solution I can see being effective here without additional mortising or holes. 
I do think it is worth addressing the overall effectiveness of handles of this type on a cutting board over some sort of mortised in finger hold.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the board linked to in the Comments above I'd say that style of handle is almost certainly glued in place.

You could pin then, with a piece of steel or brass rod (similar to how some knife handles are held in place), but with the right adhesive that sort of mechanical fixing is not at all necessary on anything that doesn't have to take much strain.

Best glues to use here I think would be epoxy (especially useful if the fit of the metal in the holes is a little sloppy) and polyurethane adhesive, like the original Gorilla Glue. Note that despite polyurethane adhesive foaming up and appearing to fill gaps it is *not* a gap-filling glue, and is only suitable here if the rods are a tight fit in the holes.

If you wanted the handles to be removable for some reason (I can't think why) you can fix something like this in place with what are called grub screws, but they would be plainly visible on the underside if they were used and if made from steel there would be the potential for them to rust, even if zinc plated.